# How would I invert text color on a pdf rendered with CoreGraphics on iOS?

Tags: ios, pdf, text, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am using an open-source PDF viewing library (VFR PDF Reader https://github.com/vfr/Reader).  I'm trying to implement "night mode" or black background with white text.  I can get the background to any color I like but I can't get the text color to change.  You can see where you can modify the background color at https://github.com/vfr/Reader/blob/master/Sources/ReaderContentPage.m in the "drawLayer" method.  It is simply changing the color of the rectangle the PDF is rendered on.

My question is: is there something I can do to the "context" that would cause the text in the pdf to change color (in my case I want white text)?  The line in question looks like this (line 558):

```
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, _PDFPageRef); // Render the PDF page into the context
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I solved the night vision:

1)I keep track of user preference (night mode or Day mode) in NSUserDefault

2) in

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CATiledLayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
```

a) retrieve the user preference

```
NSString *userViewMode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DayOrNightSetting"];
```

b) set the back ground color of the CGContextRef to white

```
 CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
```

c) replace CGContextDrawPage(Context,_PDFPageRef) with :

```
if ([userViewMode isEqualToString:@"Night"]) {
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationAtop);

        CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, _PDFPageRef);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeExclusion);
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, _PDFPageRef);
    }
    else
    {
       CGContextSetBlendMode(context,kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, _PDFPageRef);
    }
```

Comment: I am using the above mentioned code, but getting some issue with particular PDF pages, This able to covert many of the pages with black background and white text but not all. do you have any idea ? 

For some pages, it makes the background grey instead of black

Comment: @ShreeshGarg Were you rendering more than 1 page at once? This code works for me  if I am only rendering 1 page in the context.

Comment: this renders my pdf upside down