# invert white to black uiimage

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have the following UIImage:

[image]

Using Objective-C, I want to be able to invert the white to black and vice versa.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you mean black background and white signature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (UIImage *)negativeImage
{
    // get width and height as integers, since we'll be using them as
    // array subscripts, etc, and this'll save a whole lot of casting
    CGSize size = self.size;
    int width = size.width;
    int height = size.height;

    // Create a suitable RGB+alpha bitmap context in BGRA colour space
    CGColorSpaceRef colourSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *memoryPool = (unsigned char *)calloc(width*height*4, 1);
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(memoryPool, width, height, 8, width * 4, colourSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colourSpace);

    // draw the current image to the newly created context
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), [self CGImage]);

    // run through every pixel, a scan line at a time...
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        // get a pointer to the start of this scan line
        unsigned char *linePointer = &memoryPool[y * width * 4];

        // step through the pixels one by one...
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            // get RGB values. We're dealing with premultiplied alpha
            // here, so we need to divide by the alpha channel (if it
            // isn't zero, of course) to get uninflected RGB. We
            // multiply by 255 to keep precision while still using
            // integers
            int r, g, b;
            if(linePointer[3])
            {
                r = linePointer[0] * 255 / linePointer[3];
                g = linePointer[1] * 255 / linePointer[3];
                b = linePointer[2] * 255 / linePointer[3];
            }
            else
                r = g = b = 0;

            // perform the colour inversion
            r = 255 - r;
            g = 255 - g;
            b = 255 - b;

            if ( (r+g+b) / (3*255) == 0 )
            {

                linePointer[0] = linePointer[1] = linePointer[2] = 0;
                linePointer[3] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // multiply by alpha again, divide by 255 to undo the
                // scaling before, store the new values and advance
                // the pointer we're reading pixel data from
                linePointer[0] = r * linePointer[3] / 255;
                linePointer[1] = g * linePointer[3] / 255;
                linePointer[2] = b * linePointer[3] / 255;

            }
            linePointer += 4;
        }
    }

    // get a CG image from the context, wrap that into a
    // UIImage
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

    // clean up
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(memoryPool);

    // and return
    return returnImage;
}
```

I added the above method inside a UIImage extension class.

Comment: Build error at [self CGImage]: No visible @interface for 'IndexViewController' declares the selector 'CGImage'

Comment: You're right. I forgot to mention that the method was inside an extension of UIImage class...

Comment: How can this be written in swift?

Answer (score 9):

## Swift

Using `CIContext` instead of `-UIImage:CIImage` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28386697/218152), and building upon [@wtznc's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28388509/199364), here is a self-contained **IBDesignable**:

```
@IBDesignable
class InvertImage: UIImageView {

    @IBInspectable var originalImage:UIImage? = nil

    @IBInspectable var invert:Bool = false {
        didSet {
            var inverted = false
            if let originalImage = self.originalImage {
                if(invert) {
                    let image = CIImage(CGImage: originalImage.CGImage!)
                    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert") {
                        filter.setDefaults()
                        filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                        
                        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
                        let imageRef = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, fromRect: image.extent)
                        self.image = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
                        inverted = true
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(!inverted) {
                self.image = self.originalImage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, set *Original Image* instead of *Image* since *Image* will be dynamically associated:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

## Swift3

```
extension UIImage {
    func invertedImage() -> UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }
        let ciImage = CoreImage.CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert") else { return nil }
        filter.setDefaults()
        filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage else { return nil }
        guard let outputImageCopy = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: outputImageCopy, scale: self.scale, orientation: .up) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow, this affects the image (display) size

Comment: @Peter I'm curious to where. It's been a while since I last used core image, so I can't spot it. Do you have a solution for it?

Comment: This problem has been driving me crazy for a day now - somehow ARC keeps both the UIImage which is to be inverted, and the UIImage returned by the method in memory. Your code seems to do everything correctly, which is the most frustrating part. The alternatives which feed the CIImage directly into the UIImage (rather than through a CGImage, like you have) don't work either... I am very tempted to write this particular section in Objective C, and do the clean up myself!

Comment: OK so I figured out the memory leak - the UI image returned by the function keeps the dataProvider in memory. My code was keeping the image data in the graphics memory, and so keeping system memory use low.

Comment: @Peter did you solve it? Do you use Instruments for finding memory leaks? Sometimes I have retain cycles and I don't even realize it. I'm sorry that this have caused you trouble.

Comment: No problem about the trouble - your code is the recommended method. I did use instruments to see what was sucking up the memory, and then the memory graph in XCode to hunt down the source. My solution wasn't easy - I had to modify the image I am generating in the CGContext, which although difficult to write, was the best solution by far memory-wise. The code I used is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/25798154/460053

Comment: @Peter Great. Thanks for you feedback. Much appreciated. Take care.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you have to add the **Core Image framework** to your project.

*Project settings -> Targets "project name" -> Build phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> Add items -> CoreImage.framework*

[image]
Secondly, import the **Core Image header** to your implementation file.

```
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
```

Initialize an `UIImage` object to store the original file.

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageNamed"];
```

Create a `CIFilter` to define how you want to modify your original `UIImage` object.

```
CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert"];
[filter setDefaults];
[filter setValue:inputImage.CIImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
```

Create another `UIImage` object to keep modified image.

```
UIImage *outputImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:filter.outputImage];
```

Voilà! Hope it will help.

Comment: Can u post one image of what you're testing on?

Answer (score 2):

For Xamarin C# (iOS-specific; not a cross-platform solution):

```
public static UIImage InvertImageColors( UIImage original )
{
    return ApplyFilter( original, new CIColorInvert() );
}

public static UIImage ApplyFilter( UIImage original, CIFilter filter )
{
    UIImage result;
    try {
        CIImage coreImage = original.CGImage;
        filter.SetValueForKey( coreImage, CIFilterInputKey.Image );
        CIImage output = filter.OutputImage;
        CIContext context = CIContext.FromOptions( null );
        CGImage cgImage = context.CreateCGImage( output, output.Extent );
        result = UIImage.FromImage( cgImage );

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // .. Log error here ..
        result = original;
    }

    return result;
}
```

NOTE #1: Adapted from someone else's answer; I've lost track of where the original is.
NOTE #2: Deliberately done with one small step per line, so you can see the intermediate types, and easily adapt to other situations.

Also see [Xamarin docs - CIFilter class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.CoreImage.CIFilter/)